# Can displacement, stress, and strain fields be piece-wise twice differentiable?

Tags: elasticity, solid-mechanics

I have an elasticity problem where the stress field is smooth everywhere except at two isolated points.

**QUESTION:** To have a well-posed elasticity or solid mechanics problem, can the displacement, stress, and strain fields be piece-wise twice differentiable?

I think it is usually assumed that these fields are smooth (twice differentiable) everywhere, but is this a necessary assumption of the linear theory of elasticity?

**EDIT:** The answer below is very general and suggests that my question is perhaps too open-ended or general as posed. My specific problem is the following. I have an infinite solid cylinder of radius $R$ subjected to a longitudinal pressure gradient. Mathematically, the (axisymmetric) boundary conditions for this infinite cylinder problem are as follows:

(1) $\sigma_{rr}(R,z)=f(z)$,

(2) $\sigma_{rz}(R,z)=0$.

If $f(z)$ is twice differentiable for $z\in(-\infty,\infty)$, then in principle, there is no issue. My question stems from the fact that my particular $f(z)$, is continuously differentiable for $z\in(-\infty,\infty)$, but the ***second*** derivative does not exist at two isolated points $z_a,z_b$.

So my question is: Is there any theoretical constraint that precludes me from seeking a unique solution to this problem?

Comment: Suggestion to the title question (v1): Replace it e.g. with _Are displacement, stress & strain fields necessarily piece-wise twice differentiable?_ The original title question (v1) sounds like you are looking for a list of examples.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that the stress and strain fields must be twice-differentiable everywhere is sufficient, but not necessary. If is clearly false if you include problems involving several different materials as part of "the linear theory of elasticity." In this case there can be discontinuities in the strain across the boundaries between regions.

The "boundaries between regions with different materials" can be more complex than in most engineering situations - for example consider alternating layers two materials arranged in a "spiral" pattern around a point. "Common sense and intuition" are not always good guides to what is true or false mathematically!

However there are *some* necessary constraints on physically sensible solutions, for example:

1. All of the deformed material has to "fit together" without any overlaps or holes appearing. These constraints are called the Saint-Venant compatibility conditions. If $T$ is a second-order tensor (e.g. strain), this means that the function
   $$W_{ijkl} 
   = \frac{\partial^2 T_{ij}}{\partial x_k \partial x_l}
   + \frac{\partial^2 T_{kl}}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}
   - \frac{\partial^2 T_{il}}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}
   - \frac{\partial^2 T_{jk}}{\partial x_i \partial x_l}$$ 
   must be identically zero. In a simply-connected region, this implies that the strain must be the symmetric derivative of some vector field.
2. The structure must be in equilibrium everywhere, which implies that the stress tensor must be symmetric.
3. The 4th-order tensor relating stress to strain must have a large number of symmetries, because of the symmetry of the stress and strain tensors, and the symmetry of the quadratic strain energy function. Those conditions mean that only 21 of the 81 tensor components can be independent, and for isotropic materials only 2 of those 21 remain independent (for example the tensor can be written in terms of the two parameters Young's Modulus and Poisson's ratio).